# C# Date format and regional settings

Tags: c#, excel, date-format, regional-settings

UK settings: 1/7/2011 (July 1, 2011). When formatted in Excel, I use "MMM-yy", expected: Jul-11, but it gives me "Jan-11"

My code:

```
newDataRange.SetValue("Value2", arr);  //arr = "01/07/2011 00:00:00.000"
newDataRange.SetValue("NumberFormat", "MMM-yy");

        public static void SetValue(this Range range, string propertyName, object value)
        {
            var excelCulture = new CultureInfo(1033);
            var args = new object[1];
            args[0] = value;
            range.GetType().InvokeMember(propertyName, 
                BindingFlags.SetProperty | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance, null, range, args, excelCulture);
        }
```

I am confused.  Anyone knows how to solve this 
thanks

Comment: Jul-11 and Jan-11 or Jul-1 and Jan-7?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the culture you are using has a date format of mm/dd/yyyy when you want dd/mm/yyyy. Thus, your conversion is using `1` from `1/7/2011` as the month instead of the `7`.

Changing the culture to one which has a format of dd/mm/yyyy should fix your problem.

**EDIT**

As I suspected, [LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001.aspx) 1033 (0x0409) is en-US, not en-GB. en-GB is 2057 (0x0809). You should use the locale name to avoid this problem in the future, vis: `new CultureInfo("en-GB");`

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly not UK settings - the date 1/7/2011 would show up as Jan 2011 in US date format